# How to receive a variable in method automatically?

Tags: variables, methods, kohana

Is it possible to define a method like below to receive $id?

```
public function action_delete($id){

}
```

I've defined a route

```
Route::set('tweet', 'tweet/delete/<id>', array('id' => '\d+'))->defaults(array(
    'controller'=>'tweet',
    'action'=>'delete'
));
```

I remember a code snippet something like this few months ago...

Updated: I get the following error message

```
Missing argument 1 for Controller_Tweet::action_delete()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Kohana version < 3.2 then you can use this, however it is highly recommended that you get the id value with `$this->request->param('id')` -> this is the only way since 3.2 version:

```
public function action_delete(){
   $id = $this->request->param('id');
   // Rest of tour code
}
```

Comment: // ah...I'm using 3.2..that's why it is not working. Thank you for the information.

Comment: how come stackoverflow deletes @matino?

Answer (score 1):

In Kohana 3.2, this doesn't work anymore. You'll have to retrieve the variable through

```
$id = $this->request->param('id');
```

See: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Request#param